# Filter self joined and include only rows that dont match nested join

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, left-join, where-clause

I have the following pseudo tables: (PostgresSQL)

```
Payment
    id: number;
    groupId: number;
    status: [Pending|Executed];

PaymentLog
    id: number;
    paymentId: number;
    date: Date; // YYYY-DD-MM
```

- Fetch all `Payment` with `Pending`
- But exclude `Payment` if a row in `PaymentLog` referencing a `Payment` under same `groupId` and matching a specific `date`

I have tried something like

```
SELECT p1.id FROM Payment
JOIN Payment p2 ON p1.groupId = p2.groupId
LEFT JOIN PaymentLog p3 ON p2.id = p3.paymentId AND date = '2020-09-06'
WHERE
   p3.id IS NULL
GROUP BY p2.id
```

But this will also match if `PaymentLog` has items matching `groupId` in referencing `Payment` that does not match the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want `not exists`:

```
select p.* 
from payment p
where status = 'Pending' and not exists (
    select 1
    from paymentlog pl1
    inner join payment p1 on p1.paymentid = pl1.paymentid
    where p1.groupid = p.groupid and pl1.date = date '2020-09-06'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
select p.id
from payment p
where p.status = 'Pending'
and not exists (select *
                from paymentlog log 
                  join payment p2 on log.paymentid = p2.paymentid
                where log.groupid = p.groupid
                  and p2.id <> p.id
                  and log."date" = date '2020-09-06')
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
with temp as (
SELECT p1.id FROM Payment
JOIN Payment p2 ON p1.groupId = p2.groupId
--Were....
--group here if needed. or DISTINCT(p1.id)

)

select id from temp t
LEFT JOIN PaymentLog p3 ON t.id = p3.paymentId 
WHERE
date = '2020-09-06' and  p3.id IS NULL
```